# Testing whether you reach an array's last item when using reduce() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

I am trying to implement the equivalent of `.join()` using `.reduce()` to answer a quiz on [executeprogram.com](https://www.executeprogram.com/). My code passes the tests, but it seems ugly. The specific issue that I have solved in an ugly way is this: The constructed `join()` function takes an array and a separator as arguments, but the separator should not be inserted after the last item of the array when constructing the resulting joined output. This means I have to *test*, when iterating over the array with `reduce()`, whether I am at the last item (so that I can skip using the separator) *[oops: see note below]*. Using `indexOf` or `lastIndexOf` doesn't work if there are duplicate values in the array. So I created a counter. I don't like it. I would love suggestions about how to do this better. Here's the code:

```js
 function join(arr, separator) {
  let counter = 0;
  if (arr.length === 0) { return(''); }
  else { 
    return (
    arr.reduce((accumulator, item) =>
      {
        if (counter === arr.length - 1) {
          return accumulator + item;
        } else {
          counter += 1; 
          return accumulator + item + separator;
        }
      }, 
      '')
    );
  }
}
```

The tests and their expected output are below. Again, the function above passes all the tests, but I think there has to be a better way.

```js
> join(['a'], ',')
Expected: 'a'
> join(['a', 'b'], ',')
Expected: 'a,b' 
> join(['a', 'b', 'c'], '')
Expected: 'abc'
> join(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'x')
Expected: 'axbxcxd'
> join(['a', 'b'], 'COMMA')
Expected: 'aCOMMAb'
> join(['', '', ''], ',')
Expected: ',,'
> join([], ',')
Expected: ''
```

*NOTE*: After seeing all the helpful answers, I realized that the *real* cause for this ugly code was my mistaken assumption that the separator comes "after" an item. Actually, the separator comes *between* items, and you can make it come *between* every item if you insert it *before* every item except the first one. Then you don't need to test for the last item. When you remove the assumption that you need to test for the last item, everything is much simpler. So basically, I stated the problem wrong in the first place. Thanks to everyone for the answers!

Comment: The reducer function takes a third argument, the current index, and a fourth, the source array. You could clean it up a bit by using those instead of your own counter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have pointed out you could use the index and array args in the callback.

But there is another approach. You don't have to know when you've encountered the last array element. You already know what the first element is and you can just use that.

```
const join = (arr, sep=',') => arr.slice(1).reduce((acc, item) => acc + sep + item, arr[0]);
```

To further refine the function, take advantage of the little used default initial value of the accumulator. If you do not pass an initial value to the reduce() function, first execution of the callback will be given the first and second elements of the array.

```
const join = (arr, sep=',') => arr.reduce((acc, item) => acc + sep + item);
```

And to handle empty array without error...

```
const join = (arr, sep=',') => arr[0] ? arr.reduce((acc, item) => acc + sep + item) : '';
```

Comment: Well, it would cause the function to return undefined which may or may not be a problem.  But I updated the answer to a better approach anyway.

Comment: Nice one, but now you have to check if the array is empty, because otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: Yeah. Easy enough to fix. Actual fix depends on desired behavior if array is empty.

Comment: I've added a variation on your first solution.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Again, it depends what the desired behavior is if the array is empty. That would still cause reduce to throw its "no initial value" error, but a simple ternary expression would fix it.

Comment: It returns undefined if you pass undefined as the initial value argument. But it apparently doesn't like empty arrays if you use the other call signature.

Comment: `arr[0]` in the last code block should be `arr.length`, otherwise it doesn't handle an array starting with an empty string. As it currently stands: `join(["", "a", "b"]) //=> ""`

Comment: This is very helpful. Two followups: (1) as noted by @3limin4t0r, the last code block doesn't actually yield desired results for an array of non-zero length with empty slots. What does work is: `const join = (arr, sep=',') => arr.length > 0 ? arr.reduce((acc, item) => acc + sep + item) : '';`(2) these solutions point out the real error in my code, which was a very simple one: I wanted to put the separator after the item, not before, which led me to want to differentiate the last item. There's no need to do that if the separator comes before the item.

Answer (score 7):

The reduce callback is called with 4 params:

```
arr.reduce(callback( accumulator, currentValue, index, array)
```

Example:

```js
function join(arr, separator) {
  if (arr.length === 0) { return(''); }
  
  else { 
    return (
    arr.reduce((accumulator, item, counter) =>
      {
        if (counter === arr.length - 1) {
          return accumulator + item;
        } else {
          counter += 1; 
          return accumulator + item + separator;
        }
      }, 
      '')
    );
  }
}
    
    
console.log(join(['a'], ','))
console.log(join(['a', 'b'], ','))
console.log(join(['a', 'b', 'c'], ''))
console.log(join(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'x'))
console.log(join(['a', 'b'], 'COMMA'))
console.log(join(['', '', ''], ','))
console.log(join([], ','))
```

You can shorter the code a bit by:

1. Skip the empty check - if the array is empty, reduce will return the initial value (`''`).
2. Use a template string, and a ternary. If it's not the last item add the separator, if it is, use an empty string.
3. Since the counter (`i`) starts with a 0, you can skip the separator for the 1st item (0 is casted to `false`). This allows you to skip the comparison in the ternary.

```js
const join = (arr, separator) => arr.reduce((accumulator, item, i) =>
  `${accumulator}${i ? separator : ''}${item}`
, '')
    
    
console.log(join(['a'], ','))
console.log(join(['a', 'b'], ','))
console.log(join(['a', 'b', 'c'], ''))
console.log(join(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'x'))
console.log(join(['a', 'b'], 'COMMA'))
console.log(join(['', '', ''], ','))
console.log(join([], ','))
```

Another idea when changing the order (based on @JCFord `arr[0]` idea), is to destructure the array, take the 1st element (`first`), and assign it a default if it's empty. Then reduce the rest of the array, and use `first` as the initial value.

```js
const join = ([first = '', ...arr], separator) => 
  arr.reduce((accumulator, item, i) => `${accumulator}${separator}${item}`, first)
    
    
console.log(join(['a'], ','))
console.log(join(['a', 'b'], ','))
console.log(join(['a', 'b', 'c'], ''))
console.log(join(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'x'))
console.log(join(['a', 'b'], 'COMMA'))
console.log(join(['', '', ''], ','))
console.log(join([], ','))
```

Comment: That's a good approach. Anyways setting `counter += 1; ` does not have effect on the value of `counter` passed by the function.

Answer (score 4):

Here's how I do it.

Let's say you want to separate this array by commas but end it with a period.

```
let names = ['Amber', 'Bobby', 'Chris', 'Dennis', 'Edward'];
```

You can use the third index parameter "i" and compare it with the length of the array being reduced as a variable.

```
names.reduce((a, c, i) => {
   const isLast = i == names.length -1;
   return `${a}${c}` + (isLast ? '.' : ', '); 
}, "")
```

Result:
`'Amber, Bobby, Chris, Dennis, Edward.'`

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your current function by removing the initial value from [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). This will then use the first element as initial value. You've already set up a guard clause to handle empty arrays so you should be fine in that regard.

```js
function join(arr, separator) {
  if (arr.length == 0) return '';
  return arr.reduce((accumulator, item) => accumulator + separator + item);
}

console.log(join(['a'], ','))
console.log(join(['a', 'b'], ','))
console.log(join(['a', 'b', 'c'], ''))
console.log(join(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'x'))
console.log(join(['a', 'b'], 'COMMA'))
console.log(join(['', '', ''], ','))
console.log(join([], ','))
```

Another easy way to `join` an array of strings using `reduce` would be to simply not care about the additional separator it produces and [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) it off after reducing the array.

```js
function join(arr, separator) {
  return arr.reduce((accumulator, item) => accumulator + separator + item, '')
            .slice(separator.length);
}

console.log(join(['a'], ','))
console.log(join(['a', 'b'], ','))
console.log(join(['a', 'b', 'c'], ''))
console.log(join(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'x'))
console.log(join(['a', 'b'], 'COMMA'))
console.log(join(['', '', ''], ','))
console.log(join([], ','))
```